# How to map hg changeset with git changeset after converting?

Tags: git, gitlab, mercurial, changeset, hg-git

I converted my repositories from Mercurial to Git (pulled from Bitbucket(hg, Mercurial), pushed to GitLab (git)), I found that after converting from hg to git, in GitLab now, the changeset number has been changed.

I am wondering that how can I map the old hg changeset number to the new git changeset number? Is there an algorithm to do this?

Thanks,
Jennifer.

Comment: If you can explain what you use the changset #s for maybe you will get more advice. This might be an XY kind of problem.... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, there is no such algorithm

the only possible way would be to keep both repositories related, e.g. by using [hggit plugin](https://hg-git.github.io/), which maintains a map of the relation between the 2 and also keeps open the chance to pull/push across them